# C++11 name re-evaluation in completed scope of a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

It says in C++ 3.3.7.2 [basic.scope.class]

> A name `N` used in a class `S` shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of `S`.

What is an example of a translation unit where a name `N` used in a class `S` refers to a different declaration in its context than when it is re-evaluated in the completed scope of `S`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [typedef changes meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187549/typedef-changes-meaning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct X {};
struct Y {};

typedef X N;

struct S
{
    N n;
    typedef Y N;
};

$ g++ test.cpp 
9:15: error: declaration of ‘typedef struct Y S::N’ [-fpermissive]
4:11: error: changes meaning of ‘N’ from ‘typedef struct X N’ [-fpermissive]
```